# OpenLayers - what is the benefit of using ol/control/Control over defining bespoke controls?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

When creating 'controls' in OpenLayers - I.e. buttons that overlay the map and that do things when clicked, I can think of at least two methods of achieving such:

## Providing your own DOM elements, and interacting directly with the Map Object

This is my current approach. On a website I'm currently working on: https://seacrifog.saeon.ac.za/atlas, there are 2 little buttons in the top right hand corner. These buttons open side menus that contain DOM component trees and logic for interacting with the map via a reference to an OpenLayers map object.

This `map` reference is made available to all children of a component that wraps the OpenLayers library via the render-props pattern:

```
class MyMap extends Component {
  // Constructor/lifecycle methods/etc.
  this.map = new Map(...)
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div ref={this.mapRef} />
        {this.props.children({map: this.map})}
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

And then I find it quite easy to build 'controls' without using the OpenLayers `Control` class:

```
<MyMap>
{({map}) => (
  <>
    {/* Each of these renders a button and other DOM elements */}
    <Component1ThatUsesTheMap map={map} />
    <Component2ThatUsesTheMap map={map} />
    <Component3ThatUsesTheMap map={map} />
  </>
 )}
</MyMap>
```

## Using the OpenLayers ol/control/Control class

I see from [the example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/custom-controls.html) that it's possible to add buttons to a map via defining additional `Control`s as well. As far as I can tell this example shows how to define DOM elements that will be added to the Map, and how to write eventHandlers (click in this case) that will allow you to interact with the map in the way that you would like to. Which is essentially the same way that I would using my initial approach.

## Question

Is there any benefit to defining map controls using `ol/control/Control` vs not using this API? I can't think of any drawbacks to not using the `Control` class offhand (and actually... using React I can think of reasons to NOT interact directly with the DOM unless I really need to, as well as potentially interacting with the map object from a parent component). Although I'm using OpenLayers 6, I don't think the version matters in this case.